# Performing a JOIN with an ORDER BY and LIMIT in the joined table in SQL/Postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I have a table of companies and a table of transcripts that are related to those companies — many-to-one.

I want to be able to list companies that have not been checked recently AND do not have transcripts published recently.

The problem I'm running into is when I join the tables, I can't figure out how to only limit the second condition to the most recent transcript. My query is unintentionally returning companies that have recent transcripts if it detects a transcript that is older.

**Company Table**

| id | name | last_checked_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ACME | `2022-10-11 02:50:52.184975+00` |
| 2 | MeepMeep | `2022-05-12 02:50:52.184975+00` |
| 3 | TNT | `2022-05-12 02:50:52.184975+00` |

**Transcripts Table**

| id | company | published_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 1 | `2022-10-11 02:50:52.184975+00` |
| 6 | 2 | `2022-10-11 02:50:52.184975+00` |
| 7 | 2 | `2022-05-12 02:50:52.184975+00` |
| 8 | 3 | `2022-06-11 02:50:52.184975+00` |
| 9 | 3 | `2022-03-12 02:50:52.184975+00` |

**Desired Logic**

- Select `company.id`s
- Where `company.last_checked_at` is older than 1 week from today
- And only *the most recent* related `transcript.published_at` is older than 3 months from today

**Expected Behavior**

Using the data in the tables above:

- Result does not contain ACME since it was `last_checked_at` within 7 days of today
- Result does not contain MeepMeep even though `last_checked_at` is greater than 7 days, since the most recent transcript was `published_at` within 3 months of today
- Result **DOES** contain TNT since `last_checked_at` is greater than 7 days and the most recent transcript was `published_at` greater than 3 months of today

**Attempts**

```
SELECT * FROM summaries s LEFT OUTER JOIN companies c ON s.company = c.id WHERE s.published_at < now() - INTERVAL '3 months' ORDER BY s.published_at ASC limit 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using `DISTINCT ON` on the transcripts table:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (company) *
    FROM summaries
    WHERE published_at < NOW() - INTERVAL '3 months'
    ORDER BY company, published_at DESC
)

SELECT c.name, c.last_checked_at, s.published_at
FROM companies c
INNER JOIN cte s
    ON s.company = c.id
WHERE c.last_checked_at < NOW() - INTERVAL '1 week';
```

Comment:  More on [DISTINCT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)